# Eclipse doesn't show Galaxy Nexus in Android Device Chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, eclipse-adt

Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3 (API 18) connected to a Mac with OS X Yosemite GM.

Developer mode enabled, USB debugging enabled, install from unknown sources is allowed. Device is not rooted.

The device is shown in `adb devices`, I've tried both in PTP and MTP mode.

On Eclipse, the device is shown correctly in "Devices" window, file explorer allows accessing files.

In the manifest,  SDK ranges between 14 to 20 -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="200"
    android:versionName="2.00" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

</manifest>
```

For some reason, when running this project as an Android Application, the device isn't available for selection, the list of devices is empty.

Installing the APK manually on the device using `adb install` works fine, the app works fine on the device.

Eclipse works well with LG G3 with Android 4.4.

Any idea why the app doesn't appear when trying to debug/run with Eclipse?

**Update -**

I've just installed stock Android version 4.0.2 (API 14), but same problem occurs.

Comment: make `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` and try......

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: I have a similar problem. My devices don't show on the devices list or they show but are never offered on the Device Chooser when launching an app. But they don't show when I use "adb devices" either.

Comment: That's a different problem then - close eclipse, run `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`. If adb isn't recognising the devices, check for a driver (relevant to windows).

Comment: I'm having the same problem since upgrading to Yosemite: I have to unplug the device then plug it back in every time I want to test something.  It's very annoying.

Comment: That's another issue, in my case it didn't help. Once cable replaced, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved - device appeared on the list with a different USB cable.**

Strange as it may sound, an original USB to mini-USB cable that was *provided with the LG G3*, and was working well with it - didn't work with Galaxy Nexus.

The only explanation I can think of, is that one of the cables (or both) are not generic USB cables, maybe due to battery charging requirements.

Still, it doesn't explain why it was working perfectly with `adb` but not with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

try adb kill-server or from task manager hit end process for "adb.exe"
after that try adb start-server

if still not discovered
check USB connection mode
is it media mode?
try changing it to CD-ROM mode or simply try every other option.

Comment: Nope, restarting adb didn't work, nor PTP/MTP mode. BTW, there's no `adb.exe` since I'm using a Mac, as stated in the question.

Comment: my bad..there wont be any adb.exe ..:(